# How to set fixed height width to three js 3d object (sphere geometry)?

Tags: three.js, 3d, geometry

I added sphere object3D in the three js scene. but when i zoom in or zoom out, it size is getting changed, it getting smaller when i zoom out, and getting bigger when i zoom in. I want behaviour like marker on map. size of object shouldn't be changed when we zoom in / zoom out.
i am using following code to create sphere.

```
let sphereGeometry = new SphereGeometry(0.4, 10, 10);
let sphereMaterial = new MeshLambertMaterial({
            //shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
            color: 'red',
            depthTest: false,
            depthWrite: false
        }
let sphere = new Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial );
sphere.position.copy(SomeVector3Object);
sphere.material.color = new Color("#ffffff");
sphere.visible = true
scene.add(sphere);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways for some objects in your scene to remain the same size while everything else is zoomed. The examples I am including here use the mouse scroll wheel controlling camera.position.z to implement zooming, but they could be adapted to other methods.

One method is to [scale and move](https://jsfiddle.net/dx6w9gpn/) any objects that should keep their size, to counteract the zoom. One of the cubes in the linked example is translated to maintain a consistent size, while the other is not:

```
let scaleConstant = camera.position.z / 500;
mesh1.scale.x = scaleConstant;
mesh1.scale.y = scaleConstant;
mesh1.scale.z = scaleConstant;

let offsetConstant = camera.position.z * 150 / 500;
mesh1.position.x = offsetConstant;
```

Another method is to [overlay a second three.js renderer](https://jsfiddle.net/54uj7w2m/1/). If the camera associated with the bottom canvas is zoomed, while the camera associated with the overlaid canvas is not, objects within the second canvas will retain their size. This example uses simple CSS to place one renderer above the other:

```
.container, canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```